# Reading JSON in SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

In my table empid column containing values like below json format.

```
row 1->[{"id":85574},{"id":169794}]
row 2->[{"id":180313},{"id":169796},{"id":173467}]
```

i want to display empid for each row one by one like below output.

Output

```
empid
85574
169794
180313
169796
173467
```

I tried below query but it is showing Sub query returned more than 1 value

```
select 
(
SELECT StringValue from parseJSON(v1.empid) 
where Name='id'
) from emp v1 where year=1994
```

Answer (score 2):

2012 does not support JSON, but with a little parsing and string manipulation:

```
Declare @YourTable table (id int,JSON varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'[{"id":85574},{"id":169794}]'),
(2,'[{"id":180313},{"id":169796},{"id":173467}]')

Select A.ID
      ,EmpID = replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(B.RetVal,'[',''),'{',''),'}',''),']',''),'"id":','')
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.JSON,'},{','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as X 
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
             ) B
 Where B.RetVal Like '%"id":%'
```

Returns

```
ID  EmpID
1   85574
1   169794
2   180313
2   169796
2   173467
```

Comment: i tried in 2016 using parseJSON Function in below query  in my above table.But it returns Sub query returned more than 1 value.                                                  select 
(
SELECT StringValue from parseJSON(v1.empid) 
where Name='id'
) from emp v1 where year=1994

Answer (score 2):

There is one function written by PhilFactor which can be used to work with Json Strings:[Consuming JSON Strings in SQL Server](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/)

Example:

```
Select * from parseJSON('{    "Person": 
  {
     "firstName": "John",
     "lastName": "Smith",
     "age": 25,
     "Address": 
     {
        "streetAddress":"21 2nd Street",
        "city":"New York",
        "state":"NY",
        "postalCode":"10021"
     },
     "PhoneNumbers": 
     {
        "home":"212 555-1234",
        "fax":"646 555-4567"
     }
  }
}
')
```

produces

[image]

Pasting ParseJson defintion here

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.parseJSON( @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX))
    RETURNS @hierarchy TABLE
      (
       element_id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, /* internal surrogate primary key gives the order of parsing and the list order */
       sequenceNo [int] NULL, /* the place in the sequence for the element */
       parent_ID INT,/* if the element has a parent then it is in this column. The document is the ultimate parent, so you can get the structure from recursing from the document */
       Object_ID INT,/* each list or object has an object id. This ties all elements to a parent. Lists are treated as objects here */
       NAME NVARCHAR(2000),/* the name of the object */
       StringValue NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,/*the string representation of the value of the element. */
       ValueType VARCHAR(10) NOT null /* the declared type of the value represented as a string in StringValue*/
      )
    AS
    BEGIN
      DECLARE
        @FirstObject INT, --the index of the first open bracket found in the JSON string
        @OpenDelimiter INT,--the index of the next open bracket found in the JSON string
        @NextOpenDelimiter INT,--the index of subsequent open bracket found in the JSON string
        @NextCloseDelimiter INT,--the index of subsequent close bracket found in the JSON string
        @Type NVARCHAR(10),--whether it denotes an object or an array
        @NextCloseDelimiterChar CHAR(1),--either a '}' or a ']'
        @Contents NVARCHAR(MAX), --the unparsed contents of the bracketed expression
        @Start INT, --index of the start of the token that you are parsing
        @end INT,--index of the end of the token that you are parsing
        @param INT,--the parameter at the end of the next Object/Array token
        @EndOfName INT,--the index of the start of the parameter at end of Object/Array token
        @token NVARCHAR(200),--either a string or object
        @value NVARCHAR(MAX), -- the value as a string
        @SequenceNo int, -- the sequence number within a list
        @name NVARCHAR(200), --the name as a string
        @parent_ID INT,--the next parent ID to allocate
        @lenJSON INT,--the current length of the JSON String
        @characters NCHAR(36),--used to convert hex to decimal
        @result BIGINT,--the value of the hex symbol being parsed
        @index SMALLINT,--used for parsing the hex value
        @Escape INT --the index of the next escape character

      DECLARE @Strings TABLE /* in this temporary table we keep all strings, even the names of the elements, since they are 'escaped' in a different way, and may contain, unescaped, brackets denoting objects or lists. These are replaced in the JSON string by tokens representing the string */
        (
         String_ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
         StringValue NVARCHAR(MAX)
        )
      SELECT--initialise the characters to convert hex to ascii
        @characters='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
        @SequenceNo=0, --set the sequence no. to something sensible.
      /* firstly we process all strings. This is done because [{} and ] aren't escaped in strings, which complicates an iterative parse. */
        @parent_ID=0;
      WHILE 1=1 --forever until there is nothing more to do
        BEGIN
          SELECT
            @start=PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z]["]%', @json collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin);--next delimited string
          IF @start=0 BREAK --no more so drop through the WHILE loop
          IF SUBSTRING(@json, @start+1, 1)='"' 
            BEGIN --Delimited Name
              SET @start=@Start+1;
              SET @end=PATINDEX('%[^\]["]%', RIGHT(@json, LEN(@json+'|')-@start) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin);
            END
          IF @end=0 --no end delimiter to last string
            BREAK --no more
          SELECT @token=SUBSTRING(@json, @start+1, @end-1)
          --now put in the escaped control characters
          SELECT @token=REPLACE(@token, FROMString, TOString)
          FROM
            (SELECT
              '\"' AS FromString, '"' AS ToString
             UNION ALL SELECT '\\', '\'
             UNION ALL SELECT '\/', '/'
             UNION ALL SELECT '\b', CHAR(08)
             UNION ALL SELECT '\f', CHAR(12)
             UNION ALL SELECT '\n', CHAR(10)
             UNION ALL SELECT '\r', CHAR(13)
             UNION ALL SELECT '\t', CHAR(09)
            ) substitutions
          SELECT @result=0, @escape=1
      --Begin to take out any hex escape codes
          WHILE @escape>0
            BEGIN
              SELECT @index=0,
              --find the next hex escape sequence
              @escape=PATINDEX('%\x[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]%', @token collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin)
              IF @escape>0 --if there is one
                BEGIN
                  WHILE @index<4 --there are always four digits to a \x sequence   
                    BEGIN
                      SELECT --determine its value
                        @result=@result+POWER(16, @index)
                        *(CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@token, @escape+2+3-@index, 1),
                                    @characters)-1), @index=@index+1 ;

                    END
                    -- and replace the hex sequence by its unicode value
                  SELECT @token=STUFF(@token, @escape, 6, NCHAR(@result))
                END
            END
          --now store the string away 
          INSERT INTO @Strings (StringValue) SELECT @token
          -- and replace the string with a token
          SELECT @JSON=STUFF(@json, @start, @end+1,
                        '@string'+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), @@identity))
        END
      -- all strings are now removed. Now we find the first leaf.  
      WHILE 1=1  --forever until there is nothing more to do
      BEGIN

      SELECT @parent_ID=@parent_ID+1
      --find the first object or list by looking for the open bracket
      SELECT @FirstObject=PATINDEX('%[{[[]%', @json collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin)--object or array
      IF @FirstObject = 0 BREAK
      IF (SUBSTRING(@json, @FirstObject, 1)='{') 
        SELECT @NextCloseDelimiterChar='}', @type='object'
      ELSE 
        SELECT @NextCloseDelimiterChar=']', @type='array'
      SELECT @OpenDelimiter=@firstObject
      WHILE 1=1 --find the innermost object or list...
        BEGIN
          SELECT
            @lenJSON=LEN(@JSON+'|')-1
      --find the matching close-delimiter proceeding after the open-delimiter
          SELECT
            @NextCloseDelimiter=CHARINDEX(@NextCloseDelimiterChar, @json,
                                          @OpenDelimiter+1)
      --is there an intervening open-delimiter of either type
          SELECT @NextOpenDelimiter=PATINDEX('%[{[[]%',
                 RIGHT(@json, @lenJSON-@OpenDelimiter)collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin)--object
          IF @NextOpenDelimiter=0 
            BREAK
          SELECT @NextOpenDelimiter=@NextOpenDelimiter+@OpenDelimiter
          IF @NextCloseDelimiter<@NextOpenDelimiter 
            BREAK
          IF SUBSTRING(@json, @NextOpenDelimiter, 1)='{' 
            SELECT @NextCloseDelimiterChar='}', @type='object'
          ELSE 
            SELECT @NextCloseDelimiterChar=']', @type='array'
          SELECT @OpenDelimiter=@NextOpenDelimiter
        END
      ---and parse out the list or name/value pairs
      SELECT
        @contents=SUBSTRING(@json, @OpenDelimiter+1,
                            @NextCloseDelimiter-@OpenDelimiter-1)
      SELECT
        @JSON=STUFF(@json, @OpenDelimiter,
                    @NextCloseDelimiter-@OpenDelimiter+1,
                    '@'+@type+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), @parent_ID))
      WHILE (PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z0-9@+.e]%', @contents collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin))<>0 
        BEGIN
          IF @Type='Object' --it will be a 0-n list containing a string followed by a string, number,boolean, or null
            BEGIN
              SELECT
                @SequenceNo=0,@end=CHARINDEX(':', ' '+@contents)--if there is anything, it will be a string-based name.
              SELECT  @start=PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z@][@]%', ' '+@contents collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin)--AAAAAAAA
              SELECT @token=SUBSTRING(' '+@contents, @start+1, @End-@Start-1),
                @endofname=PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @token collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin),
                @param=RIGHT(@token, LEN(@token)-@endofname+1)
              SELECT
                @token=LEFT(@token, @endofname-1),
                @Contents=RIGHT(' '+@contents, LEN(' '+@contents+'|')-@end-1)
              SELECT  @name=stringvalue FROM @strings
                WHERE string_id=@param --fetch the name
            END
          ELSE 
            SELECT @Name=null,@SequenceNo=@SequenceNo+1 
          SELECT
            @end=CHARINDEX(',', @contents)-- a string-token, object-token, list-token, number,boolean, or null
          IF @end=0 
            SELECT  @end=PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z0-9@+.e][^A-Za-z0-9@+.e]%', @Contents+' ' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin)
              +1
           SELECT
            @start=PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z0-9@+.e][A-Za-z0-9@+.e]%', ' '+@contents collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin)
          --select @start,@end, LEN(@contents+'|'), @contents  
          SELECT
            @Value=RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@contents, @start, @End-@Start)),
            @Contents=RIGHT(@contents+' ', LEN(@contents+'|')-@end)
          IF SUBSTRING(@value, 1, 7)='@object' 
            INSERT INTO @hierarchy
              (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, Object_ID, ValueType)
              SELECT @name, @SequenceNo, @parent_ID, SUBSTRING(@value, 8, 5),
                SUBSTRING(@value, 8, 5), 'object' 
          ELSE 
            IF SUBSTRING(@value, 1, 6)='@array' 
              INSERT INTO @hierarchy
                (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, Object_ID, ValueType)
                SELECT @name, @SequenceNo, @parent_ID, SUBSTRING(@value, 7, 5),
                  SUBSTRING(@value, 7, 5), 'array' 
            ELSE 
              IF SUBSTRING(@value, 1, 7)='@string' 
                INSERT INTO @hierarchy
                  (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, ValueType)
                  SELECT @name, @SequenceNo, @parent_ID, stringvalue, 'string'
                  FROM @strings
                  WHERE string_id=SUBSTRING(@value, 8, 5)
              ELSE 
                IF @value IN ('true', 'false') 
                  INSERT INTO @hierarchy
                    (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, ValueType)
                    SELECT @name, @SequenceNo, @parent_ID, @value, 'boolean'
                ELSE
                  IF @value='null' 
                    INSERT INTO @hierarchy
                      (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, ValueType)
                      SELECT @name, @SequenceNo, @parent_ID, @value, 'null'
                  ELSE
                    IF PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @value collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_Bin)>0 
                      INSERT INTO @hierarchy
                        (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, ValueType)
                        SELECT @name, @SequenceNo, @parent_ID, @value, 'real'
                    ELSE
                      INSERT INTO @hierarchy
                        (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, ValueType)
                        SELECT @name, @SequenceNo, @parent_ID, @value, 'int'
          if @Contents=' ' Select @SequenceNo=0
        END
      END
    INSERT INTO @hierarchy (NAME, SequenceNo, parent_ID, StringValue, Object_ID, ValueType)
      SELECT '-',1, NULL, '', @parent_id-1, @type
    --
       RETURN
    END
GO
```